# Can we return Data in JSON format in flask using Neo4j queries?

Tags: python, json, flask, neo4j

I want to return data in JSON format from Flask method. My Code is written in Flask and Neo4j is used for storing Data.

As of now, my code is:

```
result = session.run("MATCH (p:Person {name:$username})-[:PURCHASED]->(:Product)<-[:PURCHASED]-(p2:Person)-[:PURCHASED]->(pd2:Product)"
        "WHERE NOT (p)-[:PURCHASED]->(pd2)"
        "RETURN pd2.title as product_title, pd2.description as product_details" , username=username)
for record in result:
    print("%s %s" % (record["product_title"], record["product_details"]))
    return 'Loop Entered'
return 'OK'
```

I tried using 'jsonify' as below but got Type error as : `TypeError: ('product_title', 'product_details')`

```
return jsonify([record[("product_title","product_details")] for record in result])
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Comment: I get Type error when using jsonify : `TypeError: ('product_title', 'product_details')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to do this:

`return jsonify({record["product_title"]: record["product_details"] for record in result})`
or even

```
return jsonify([
    {
        "product_title": record["product_title"],
        "product_details": record["product_details"],
    }
    for record in result

])
```

?

You can access only one key at a time when using `dict` type in Python